# ¿Cómo modificar valores en leyenda usando "scale_fill" con variable contínua en ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quiero que aparezca en la leyenda en el siguiente gráfico que el máximo de la variable "Ramoneo" es 5

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rcartocolor)

ggplot(data = QIlex21_22) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Tratamiento, y = Individuos, fill = Ramoneo),
             size = 2,
             alpha = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~ Habitat ~ Año) +
    labs(title = 'Regeneración Quercus ilex',
         x = 'Tratamiento',
         y = 'Nº de brinzales') +
    theme_test() +
    scale_fill_carto_c(palette = 'Temps')
```

Probé a usar `scale_fill_hue()` pero los valores de Ramoneo son continuos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya que `scale_color_hue()` aplica a variables discretas ('Evenly spaced colours for discrete data'), para modificar valores en la leyenda pueden ser modificados los argumentos `breaks` y `labels` dentro de la función `scale`.

En éste ejemplo uso `scale_fill_viridis()` con los valores entre 1 a 8.

```
mtcars # uso éstos datos disponibles en R para facilitar la reproducción del ejemplo

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, fill = carb)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(breaks = c(1:8), labels = c(1:8)) +
    facet_wrap(~ vs)
```

Los nombres pasados pueden ser arbitrarios. Para ello se puede crear un vector con longitud igual a los valores de `breaks` que contenga caracteres:

```
> lab = c(letters[1:8]) # creando un vector de caracteres
> lab
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

O también un vector numérico con valores que no correspondan con los valores en la variable:

```
> lab = c(1:7,10)
> lab
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 10
```

Luego, puede utilizarse esos nombres para identificar los valores en el argumento `labels`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, fill = carb)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(breaks = c(1:8), labels = lab) +
    facet_wrap(~ vs)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Aunque creo que no me he explicado del todo bien. Lo que quiero saber es si en la leyenda puedo reflejar de alguna manera que el máximo de la variable "carb" es 10 aun que el máximo valor en este caso sea 8. Por ejemplo, si pongo `scale_fill_viridis_c(breaks = c(1:10), labels = c(1:10))` la leyenda no cambia. Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Hola David! Edité la respuesta. Es ésa la solución que buscas?